# I'm not able to get data from a Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase for an Android project and it works well while pushing the data to a server, but when retrieving the data, I get nothing.

here is the structure for my firebase

[image: This image contains My Firebase database]

and here is my code for retrieving the data form Firebase

```
mRef.child("User").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

             counter = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
             for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 post = postSnapshot.getValue(SettersGetters.class);
                 nicuNames.add(post.getNicuName());
                 nicuAddresses.add(post.getNicuAddress());
                 niucCount.add(post.getNicuCount());
                 nicuPrices.add(post.getNicuCount());
                 nicuPhones.add(post.getNicuPhone());
                 nicuUpdate.add(post.getNicuUpdate());
                 nicuLat.add(post.getNicuLat());
                 nicuLng.add(post.getNicuLng());
                 nicuDes.add(post.getNicuDesc());
                 a++;
                 Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"jhkjhk", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 System.out.println(nicuNames.get(0));
             }
             //Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"jhkjhk" + a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

         }

     });
```

While making a Toast to print at least the number of Children, it returns 0 every time

```
Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,a+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to listen to children events of `User` key, not value events.

Replace

```
mRef.child("User").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

With

```
mRef.child("User").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
```

---

Then, implement

- `onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName)`
- `onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName)`

And from there, you map a `DataSnapshot` to a (preferrably better named class than) `SettersGetters.class`

Comment: are you using FirebaseRecyclerView?

Comment: I would if I had to, but I've never used it, no.

Comment: use firebaseRecyclerView its very easy to use as it has all these functions included in it. check this link - https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: I know what it is... I just don't need it, so please stop advertising it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mRef.child("User").child("Kfx7408plvgugiMR1Se").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

             counter = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
             for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 post = postSnapshot.getValue(SettersGetters.class);
                 nicuNames.add(post.getNicuName());
                 nicuAddresses.add(post.getNicuAddress());
                 niucCount.add(post.getNicuCount());
                 nicuPrices.add(post.getNicuCount());
                 nicuPhones.add(post.getNicuPhone());
                 nicuUpdate.add(post.getNicuUpdate());
                 nicuLat.add(post.getNicuLat());
                 nicuLng.add(post.getNicuLng());
                 nicuDes.add(post.getNicuDesc());
                 a++;
                 Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"jhkjhk", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 System.out.println(nicuNames.get(0));
             }
             //Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"jhkjhk" + a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

         }

     });
```

Comment: This seems bad... `.child("Kfx7408plvgugiMR1Se")`. That ID is auto-assigned and you can't know that ahead of time

Comment: what i wanted to tell you is that you are providing incorrect reference to your database.

Post your whole could and then only one could help you.

Comment: *Not my code. I'm saying your answer doesn't seem right